# I'd like to make it possible, when user reaches the last image to show the first one after it and so on

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, circular-buffer

I've got an `UIScrollView` and in it different images (about 30). I'd like to make it possible, when user reaches the last image to show the first one after it and so on. And I want to implement the same feature with the first image (to go to the last one). I'd like to loop the images smoothly that user won't even notice that he is making another loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [article](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html) on how to do it. It describe how and also include code - even if it's in Objective-C (but it should be easy to convert to C#).